# Run terminal commands from python using Subprocess

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, subprocess

I'm trying to run a terminal command from my django but getting an error.

Here's the command I want to run:

```
kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f FILE_PATH)
```

Here's what I have tried:
From **views.py**

```
nodesvc = subprocess.call('kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f ' + os.path.join(path) + '/nodeService.yaml)',
                                      shell=True)
```

I'm creating a file in temporary  directory and pass it's path here, which is correct.

Here's the error :

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f /var/folders/g2/8fzl8mjj5xxfqdfvrl7v3q_40000gn/T/tmpstfcq3es/nodeService.yaml)'
```

I think that something wrong with curly braces '(',
How can I resole this issue, help me please!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you run this command in terminal?

Comment: @Sraw  yup! It's working from terminal.

Comment: keep os.path.join(path) in a variable and append that variable in the subprocess.call

Comment: This is a shell error and not a python error btw.

Comment: What happens when you run the command in the error ? The one after `/bin/sh: -c: line 0:`

Comment: remove ')' after yaml and also '(' It will work

Comment: @PrakashPalnati, it doesn't work in this way!

Comment: Have tried various option suggested here, use variable instead of os.path.join directly, nothing happens after shell error, after removing curly braces it says `istioctl : no such file  or directory`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that whatever shell python is invoking does not have support for process substitution via `<(..)`. What works for me:

```
subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", "wc -l <(sort something.txt)"])
```

This forces to invoke the shell as bash, which usually supports process substitution. For your command, this should work:

```
subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", 'kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f ' + os.path.join(path) + '/nodeService.yaml)'])
```

Edit: adapt for question

Comment: How can I arrange this command `kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f FILE_PATH)` according to your suggestion?

Comment: it returns `/bin/bash: istioctl: command not found
error: no objects passed to apply
1`

Comment: Sounds like istioctl is not in the PATH. Try to replace istioctl with the full path to this command.

Comment: PATH is not global. It may be different in your Django environment. Even bash may fiddle with it before it executes the commands. You can check by replacing the command you want to execute by `echo $PATH`.